# Dominated probability distributions on the real line example

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am familiar with the dominance and density on measure spaces but I am getting confused when putting it in probability distribution on the real line. I went through material in [Meaning of a probability distribution being dominated by a measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098146/meaning-of-a-probability-distribution-being-dominated-by-a-measure) but still do not understand fully on what this represents. Is there any examples for dominated probability distribution on the real line that could clarify this matter to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A probability distribution is continuous iff it is dominated by Lebesgue measure, for example.

Comment: @DavidKraemer But the Cantor measure is continuous but not dominated by Lebesgue measure, I think.

Comment: @kimchilover I think a probability distribution is continuous means that it has a density wrt Lebesgue. Cantor measure doesn't have this property.

Comment: @DavidKraemer I however think a probability distribution is continuous means that it has no atoms.  A prob measure decomposes into the sum of a discrete part and a continuous part; the continuous part further decomposes into the sum of a singular continuous part and an absolutely continuous part.

Comment: Oh, I accept your correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any probability distribution with a probability density function is dominated by Lebesgue measure.  That is, if $P$ is specified by a formula $P(A)=\int_Af(x)\,dx$, for some non-negative function $f$ for which $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\,dx=1$, then $P$ is dominated by Lebesgue measure.  Thus, the many famous named probability distributions (the Gaussian, the Cauchy, the chi-squared, etc) with density functions are all dominated by Lebesgue measure.

One way to understand the Radon-Nikodym theorem is that it provides the converse to this assertion: *all* probability measures dominated by Lebesgue measure have densities.

(This is slightly different (as discussed in comments) from the condition that $P$ be *continuous*, that is, that the function $x\mapsto P((-\infty,x])$ is continuous.  If $P$ is dominated by Lebesgue measure it is continuous, but there exist examples of continuous distributions without density functions.)